# Determinate TableColumn's data type

Tags: java, tablecolumn

For example I have this random table:
[image]

How can I determinate the data type of each column:
First column contains data with String type.
Second column contains data with Double type
Third column contains data with String type.

Comment: You tagged your question with `java`, so I guess you're using JDBC. Have a look at `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType()`.

Comment: @blafasel Thnx for your time and sry I wasn't very clear, I'm talking about jtable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below...

```
    //creating a table
    MyTableModel mod = new MyTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(mod);
    table.setVisible(true);
    table.getColumnClass(1); // will return the data type class of first column
    table.isCellEditable(1, 0);
```

Comment: Thnx for your time and sry I wasn't very clear, I'm talking about jtable.

Comment: Yes that's it thnx :)